# Azure SQL database data archive solution

Tags: azure-sql-database

We have Azure SQL database , we need build data archival solution to manage data more than 2 years old.

**Requirement:**

1. Archive and delete more than 2 years data from **certain transaction tables**.
2. Should archive the data in **low cost storage.**
3. Should be able to **quickly restore** the data if required.
4. Looking for **recurring job** need to execute on every week.

Please recommend an azure solution to achieve this.

Comment: What data volume are you handling in these more than 2 years time span?

Comment: 3-4 tables ( 50 columns) - 2 million records.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the approaches you can try:

1. If you want to archive the complete database, you can Export a `bacpac` directly from Azure Portal. This `bacpac` file will be stored in existing Azure Storage account. Once done, you can delete the data from database. Refer [Export to a BACPAC file - Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export).

[image]

If you need to only archive 2 years of data, you can create a Stored Procedure for each table in your database. You can run that SP using [Stored Procedure activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-stored-procedure) in **Azure Data Factory.**

2. The cheapest (free) option to store archive data is by creating `bacpac` file and store it in local machine. Or else you can use Blob Storage cold storage service for archiving data.
3. To restore data from `bacpac`, just simply import the bacpac file in your database. To restore from Blob Storage, **update the container from cool to hot** and use ADF to copy from that file into destination database.
4. If you are using SP activity in ADF as mentioned in point 1, you can **trigger the ADF pipeline to run your SP weekly/monthly** or whenever as per your requirement. Refer [Schedule Trigger in ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger?tabs=data-factory).